# No implicit reference conversion from a db model entity to a base model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to avoid creating repetitions of CRUD controllers throughout my application for every model entity and pursue a DRY approach.

I am trying to architect a solution where I create a generic BaseController into an existing minimal .net 7.0 web api that uses AdventureWorks database and EF core.

I have a products controller which currently inherits ControllerBase, but when I try and inherit BaseController I get
CS0311: The type 'AdventureWorks2017API.Models.Product' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'BaseController'

There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AdventureWorks2017API.Models.Product' to 'AdventureWorks2017API.BaseModel'

So, should I attempt the implicit conversion by modifying the BaseController or is that the wrong approach here.

Should I attempt to say 'where an array of TEntity' in the BaseController ControllerBase inheritance and as well as the BaseModel, specify all of the AdventureWorks model entities I need aswell ?

```
using AdventureWorks2017API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AdventureWorks2017API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : BaseController<Product> // ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AdventureWorks2017Context _context;

        public ProductsController(AdventureWorks2017Context context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetAllProducts")]
        public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return _context.Products.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using AdventureWorks2017API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AdventureWorks2017API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class BaseController<TEntity> : ControllerBase where TEntity: BaseModel
    {
        // protected readonly BaseControllerDBContext _context;
        protected readonly AdventureWorks2017Context _context;
        protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet { get; set; }

        // public BaseController(BaseControllerDBContext context)
        public BaseController(AdventureWorks2017Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(int count = -1, int skip = -1, string searchTerm = "", string sortBy = "")
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot search in base controller.");
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot sort in base controller.");
            }

            if (count != -1 && skip != -1)
            {
                return await _dbSet.Skip(skip).Take(count).ToListAsync();
            }

            return await _dbSet.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public virtual async Task<TEntity?> GetAsync(Guid id)
        {
            return await _dbSet.Where(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(Guid id)
        {
            var entity = await _dbSet.Where(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (entity != null)
            {
                _dbSet.Remove(entity);
            }     
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual async Task<TEntity> CreateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public virtual async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Update(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share `Product` and `BaseModel` definitions?

Comment: @Guru - I'll get these asap!

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, The most likely cause of this error message is your `Product` model doesn't inherit from `BaseModel` model, So you can check your `Product` if it is:

```
public class Product: BaseModel
{
    //..........
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paul Kersey, Have you solved this issue now?

Comment: Hi, not yet! The Product model (along with tens of other models generated by the EF Context) lives in my main API project, but the repository classes are in a separate class library project.

It would be an impossible task to somehow archtect that approach!

Comment: The Product.cs class is too big to post here.

Comment: It seems you can't change your product model, In my opinion, you can try to create a DTO of product and  inherit from BaseModel, Then use this model in ProductsController

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'm going to rely on Entity Framework, rather than try and implement the onion architecture, because it can lead to too many rabbit holes and anti-patterns!